# Leaving group channels as a bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

I made a telegram bot using telepot, one of the issues I have is that groups can still invite and make the bot join their channels, even with `/setjoingroups` disabled. Is there a way to list these groups and leave them from the code or from @BotFather ?

thanks

Comment: adding the code to your question would be kinda helpful?

Comment: Hi @Vincentino, I don't have an issue with the code itself. I am just trying to find a way to list/leave channels with [telepot](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You can look bot settings inline mode and group privacy

Comment: Please add this as a comment, because it looks like you are suggesting something. If you want to keeps this as an answer consider adding more details.